# Which function is used to paint a terrain with the unity terrain engine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, paint, terrain

I am trying to paint a terrain via C# script. I want to be able to paint grass at certain points on a given terrain, not in the editor, but on runtime. The only thing I need to know is: **Where is the actual function that is used to paint the terrain (usually with the brush tool) in unity editor?** It must be somewhere in a script so I can call it, doesn't it? I know there are other work-arounds but I am specifically interested in this one.
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

[`Terrain::TerrainData::SetAlphamaps()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainData.SetAlphamaps.html).

There's some sample code on that page as well:

```
// Blend the two terrain textures according to the steepness of
// the slope at each point.
function Start () {
    var map: float[,,] = new float[t.terrainData.alphamapWidth, t.terrainData.alphamapHeight, 2];

    // For each point on the alphamap...
    for (var y = 0; y < t.terrainData.alphamapHeight; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < t.terrainData.alphamapWidth; x++) {
            // Get the normalized terrain coordinate that
            // corresponds to the the point.
            var normX = x * 1.0 / (t.terrainData.alphamapWidth - 1);
            var normY = y * 1.0 / (t.terrainData.alphamapHeight - 1);

            // Get the steepness value at the normalized coordinate.
            var angle = t.terrainData.GetSteepness(normX, normY);

            // Steepness is given as an angle, 0..90 degrees. Divide
            // by 90 to get an alpha blending value in the range 0..1.
            var frac = angle / 90.0;
            map[x, y, 0] = frac;
            map[x, y, 1] = 1 - frac;
        }
    }

    t.terrainData.SetAlphamaps(0, 0, map);
}
```

Where `t` is presumably a preset reference to a Terrain component not otherwise declared in the example.

Comment: I think your example is in Unityscript instead of C#

Comment: @Programmer That's Unity's fault. All I did was copy-paste it (and my default is C#, but this example uses the same snippet for both the C# and JS view settings).

Comment: well the difference is marginal at best

Comment: @yes Yes. (do I really need 6 more characters?) Switching from (strict) JS to C# is two, easy, regex expressions.

Comment: @Draco18s TY very much. This one is for painting textures right? What about painting grass prefabs?

Comment: I'm sure the terrain data class has a method for it, but I haven't used it, so I don't know how it works.